# Dual-boot (Linuxmint and ChromeOS) on Samsung ARM Chromebook

Tags: multi-boot, linux-mint, chromebook

Two weeks ago I bought a Samsung Exynus 5200 Chromebook. It has 2 GB memory, a 16 GB SSD, an ARM-processor Mali-T 604 and ships with Chrome OS named Snow-Premier GE 8429. 
I want to work with Linux on it. And I tested several installations of ChromeOS with the possiblity to boot:

- Ubuntu, placed in 10 GB of the SSD;
- Ubuntu placed on a SD-card;
- Ubuntu placed on a USBstick;
- XFCE with crouton;
- Unity with crouton.

But I prefer Linuxmint.

So my question is: Is there anyone who knows how to install Linux mint as a dual-boot system with ChromeOS?

Answer (score 0):

you simpely can't add linux mint to a ARM chromebook without having lag problems and a riks of chrashes however you can still downlad it if u check out this website :

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/install-linux-chromebook/

in the post he dose tell you the risks of installation on the ARM powered chromebooks and if you want linux the you should buy a cheep windows laptop that can downlad it directly insted of coding a chromebook evan if you was abel to get linux mint you would not be able to run root to acess the main fetures of linux I am currently wirting this on June 26th 2015 this question was asked two years ago so like me you probly would of upgraded to windows by now but if anyone alse wanted to know the awser to the question then here it is thank you for taking the time to read this post